# How can I sanitize text from a codename one textarea?

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a text area in a form that is filled by the user. There are no constraints on the text area.

Because of the prepondernce of differnt types of mobile keyboards, I want to make sure that the text I get from the text area is sanitized. i.e. It should be stripped clean of any emoticons or hidden characters. It should only contain alphaumeric and punctuation characters.

What is the best way to do this in codename one? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? What does your research tell you? What tactics have or haven't worked?

Comment: Actually, if you're using a JSON library, it must deal with all the escapes. It's better than assembling a JSON by hand.

Comment: I have tried using regex on the string that I get from the textarea, it works but I was wondeirng if there is perhaps a cleaner way of doing it. I am using the standard JSON parser/encoder in codename one.

Comment: *"this is to prevent any JSON parsing and db insert errors on my server backend"* The only way those could occur is if you're not correctly serializing to JSON or using PreparedStatements/correctly escaping your DB inputs.

Comment: Well I do all of those things, but because of encoding, apple emoticons  cause problems (am I allowed to say that?) with JSON parsing on my server end. I'd prefer not to deal with them as displaying them on a web browser (ie8 in this case) causes further issues

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a regexp and there is no cleaner way. However, I believe you are approaching the problem sub-optimally.

You can detect the browser used by the user from the user agent string and based on that you can determine whether emoticons should be shown or not. Before you render the content, check whether emoticons should be shown. If not, then filter out unneeded characters. If yes, then show those emoticons.

Finally, I must mention that you must protect your database against SQL injection attempts or accidental bugs and you should make sure that XSS is not possible either.

Comment: That would be a good approach. You can use the builtin validation framework and regex to do that: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/validation-regex-masking.html